# Exception trying to get parentContentControlOrNullObject property

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I´m trying to get the Title and the order of all the content controls in a Word document. The following code works:

```
 function readContentControlsTitle() {

    Word.run(function (context) {
        var myDocParagraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;

        context.load(myDocParagraphs, 'text, outlineLevel');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < myDocParagraphs.items.length; i++) {

                var parContentControl = myDocParagraphs.items[i].parentContentControlOrNullObject;

                context.load(parContentControl, 'title');

                paragraphContentControls.push(parContentControl);
            }

            return context.sync().then(function () {

                for (var iCount = 0; iCount < paragraphContentControls.length; iCount++) {

                    if (paragraphContentControls[iCount].title != null) {
                            // Some stuff with paragraphContentControls[iCount].title
                    }
                }

                return context.sync();
            })
        })
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

The problem arise when I insert a table of contents in the document. In that case, I always get an exception in the second context.sync. If I remove the table of contents, it works again. The output of the exception is:

Debug info: {"code":"GeneralException","message":"GeneralException","errorLocation":"Paragraph.parentContentControlOrNullObject"}

My Word version: 16.0.7927.1020

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for discovering the issue. Yes it is a bug. It is fixed now and should be released next month. Before the fix, you can put parentContentControlOrNullObject in a try/catch.  Thanks.